# What is a platform independent way of getting unique value of current instance (e.g. pid) in C++

Tags: c++, platform-independent

I would like to get a some kind (doesn't matter whether it's a process id or anything) of a unique integer value of current instance in C++ in a **platform independent** manner (that means no #if #else macro switch).

time based value would not be reliable since two instances can start at the same time.

Is there any way of achieving this?

EDIT: It doesn't have to be globally unique. it just needs to be unique system wide.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but you want to give unique IDs to each instance of your program that is run? Could you do something like make each application generate a UUID on start up and use that as the instance identifier?

Comment: umm uuid based on what? time? hardware id?

Comment: I imagine other platforms have an equivalent to hwnd on Windows.  Just make an integer type that will fit all of them, and stuff that process ID in there.

Comment: Use [`boost::uuid`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html), which supports the 5 different versions of UUID, and I think defaults to version 4, which is based on random numbers and not potentially identifying information about your system.

Comment: Hmm.. I'd rather use #if #else switch than using a third party library( too heavy and an overkill )... I'll eventually accept the answer if there's none that uses C++(also C if none exists) built-in library but answers without using third party library would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, the answer is no, not without using platform-specific functionality.

### [C++03]

The C++ language itself does not provide any mechanism to do this.  In fact, C++ itself knows nothing about processes or interprocess communication.  Without using platform-specific functionality -- either hand-rolled by you, which means `#ifdef`s, or in some cross-platform 3rd part library like Boost, which also means `#ifdef`s -- this cannot be done.

...and...

### [C++11]

The C++ language has a basic concept of threads, but it provides no mechanism (that I can see) to create an interprocess communication mechanism, so the above still applies.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Boost process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/). Might be exactly what you're looking for. If you don't want to include the library, you can take a look at how the functionality is implemented.

Comment: Yes, exactly !  Excerpt from boost_process/boost/process/self.hpp:       `self() : 
#if defined(BOOST_POSIX_API) 
       process(::getpid()) 
#elif defined(BOOST_WINDOWS_API) 
       process(::GetCurrentProcessId()) 
#endif 
       { 
       } 
`

Comment: Nowadays self.hpp has disappeared; the call has been replaced by  `boost::this_process::get_id()`

Answer (score 1):

This might be an overkill, but take a look into [QUuid](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/quuid.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need [Universally unique identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)